# How to convert Yaw, Pitch, Roll and Acceleration value to cartesian system?

Tags: math

I am having readings of Yaw, pitch, Roll, Rotation matrix, Quaternion and Acceleration. These reading are taken with frequency of 20 (per second). They are collected from the mobile device which is moving in 3D space from one position to other position.

I am setting reference plane by multiplying inverse matrix to the start postion. The rest of the readings are taken by considering the first one as a reference one. Now I want to convert these readings to 3D cartesian system.

How to convert it? Can anyone please help?

Comment: This does not seem to be a programming question.  It is better suited to the math forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok basically yaw, pitch and roll are the [euler angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles), with them you got your rotation matrix already. 
Quaternions are aquivalent to that, with them you can also calculate the rotation matrix you need.

If you have rotation matrices `R_i` for every moment `i` in your `l=20secs` interval. Than these rotations are relative the the one applied at `R_(i-1)` you can calculate their rotation relative to the first position. So `A_i = R_1*...*R_i` but after all you could also just safe the new direction of travel (safes calculations).

So asuming that the direction of travel is `d_0 = (1,0,0)` at first. You can calculate the next by `d_i = R_i*d_(i-1)` (always norm `d_(i-1)` because it might get smaller or bigger due to error). The first position is `p` and your start speed is `v_0 = (0,0,0)` and finally the acceleration is `a_i`. You need to calculate the vectorial speed `v_i` for every moment:

```
v_i = v_(i-1) + l*a_i*A_i*d_0 = v_(i-1) + l*a_i*d_i
```

Now you basically know where you are moving, and what kind of speed you use, so your position `p_i` at the moment `i` is given by:

```
`p_i = p_0 + l * ( v_1 + v_2 + ... + v_i)`
```

For the units:

```
a_i = [m/s^2]^3
v_i = [m/s]^3
p_i = [m]^3
```

#### Precision

Now some points to the precision of your position calculation (just if you want to know how good it will work). Suppose you have an error `e>= ||R_i*v-w||` (where `w` is the correct vector). in the data you calculate the rotation matrices with. Your error is multipling itself so your error in the `i` moment is `e_i <= e^i`.
Then because you apply `l` and `a_i` to it, it becomes:

```
f_i <= l*a_i*e^i
```

But you are also adding up the error when you add up the speed, so now its `g_i <= f_1+...+f_i`. And yeah you also add up for the position (both sums over `i`):

```
h_i <= g_1+...+g_i = ΣΣ (l*a_i*e^i) = l* ΣΣ (a_i*e^i)
```

So this is basically the maximum difference from your position `p_i` to the correct position `w` (`||p_i - w|| <= h_i`).
This is still not taking in account that you don't get the correct acceleration from your device (I don't know how they normally do this), because correct would be:

```
a_i = ||∫a_i(t) dt||  (where a_i(t) is vectorial now)
```

And you would need to calculate the difference in direction (your rotation matrix) as:

```
 Δd_i = (∫a_i(t) dt)/a_i   (again a_i(t) is vectorial)
```

So apart from the errors you get from the error in your rotations from your device (and from floating point arithmetic), you have an error in your acceleration, I won't calculate that now but you would substitute `a_i = a_i + b_i`.

So I'm pretty sure it will be far off from the real position. You even have to take in account that you're speed might be non zero when it should be!

But that beeing said, I would really like to know the precision you get after implementing it, that's what always keept me from trying it.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. +1 for same. I will try above code and let you know the results.